# I'm having trouble with the logic in a for-loop

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I am trying to write a loop that will generate a random number between 0 and 2 and use this number as an index for an array. This will be done 3 times and each following number should be different ( eg.I have an int array {1,2,3}.  When it gets put through the program it prints `3-1-2, 3-2-1, 2-3-1, 1-2-3, 2-1-3` etc.but never `3-1-3` or the like where a number, in this case 3, is repeated.

Here is the code I am using to try to do this:

```
int ans1 = getRand();
int ans2 = getRand();
int ans3 = getRand();

public int getRand()
{
    done = true;
    while (done)
    {
        tempAns = rand.Next(0, 2);
        done = false;
        foreach (int i in answersDone)
        {
            if (tempAns == i)
            {
                done = true;

            }
        }
    }
    answersDone.Add(tempAns);
    return tempAns;
}
```

When I run this code goes into an infinite loop and I'm not sure why.

Comment: usually, we loop `while( !done )`.

Comment: What is in `answersDone`?

Comment: because in your 'foreach' your if 'if' would be finally becaome true and inside of that you make your 'done' true, so your while would never exit.

Comment: change this `done = true;` to false initially

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby answersDone just saves the values for tempAns that have run before. Its initially empty and in the final loop it has the two other numbers that have went through the loop.

Comment: why are you assigning ` done = false;` inside the while loop before even checking / getting into your inner loop...

Answer (score 1):

`Random.Next` doesn't guarntee the number to be unique. Also your range is from 0 to 2 and chances are you will get duplicate values.

```
public List<int> answersDone = new List<int>();
```

Function for generating new random number

```
private void NewNumber()
{
    MyNumber = rand.Next(0, 2);
    if (!answersDone.Contains(MyNumber))
        answersDone.Add(MyNumber);
}
```

Check count if it has 3 records.

```
if(answersDone.Count != 2){
    NewNumber();
}else{
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because in your 'foreach' your if 'if' would be finally becaome true and inside of that you make your 'done' true, so your while would never exit.
i think this is what you want :

```
int ans1 = getRand();
int ans2 = getRand();
int ans3 = getRand();

public int getRand()
{

 done = false;
 while(!done)
 {
     tempAns  = rand.Next(0, 2);
     done = false;
     foreach(int i in answersDone)
     {
         if (tempAns == i)
         {
             done = true;

         }
     }
 }
    answersDone.Add(tempAns);
    return tempAns;
}
}
```

**you can also use `break` as follow :**

```
int ans1 = getRand();
int ans2 = getRand();
int ans3 = getRand();

public int getRand()
{

 done = false;
 while(!done)
 {
     tempAns  = rand.Next(0, 2);
     done = false;
     foreach(int i in answersDone)
     {
         if (tempAns == i)
         {
             done = true;
             break;
         }
     }
 }
    answersDone.Add(tempAns);
    return tempAns;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To randomize your array:

```
int[] inputArray = {1, 2, 3};
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] randomArray = inputArray.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```